# Getting Yammer Access Token in C# Console application

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, yammer

I would like to post to my company Yammer feed from Console C# application.
Before, I created Javascript and Rest Application. But now, I do not know How to get access Token.

I tryed to use HttpWebRequest Class to Endpoint

```
https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=[my_client_id] &response_type=code&redirect_uri=[redirect_url]
```

However, Httpresponse Not contain "code".

Someone who know get access token, please tell me how to get access token.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to get a sample token. You can now generate one within the screen where you created your client application. Go to https://www.yammer.com/client_applications/ and select the app you want to get a token for.

There is a link for 'Generate a developer token for this application'

For the API request you have listed I think the user would need to authenticate first then get a dialog box to accept\reject the app which would then redirect to get the code to exchange for an access token. 
Docs are here:
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2